# Returning multiple values from single Java method

Tags: java, return-type

Here's the scenario:

Caller of the Java method `public _____ submitData(Data data)` expects a confirmation number when submitted data has been successfully processed as well as a return code if it hasn't.

I could think of three ways to do this.

Method 1:

Return a serializable object containing confirmation number and ReturnCode as instance fields.

```
public class Foo {

    private String confirmationNumber;

    private ReturnCode returnCode;

    public Foo(ReturnCode returnCode) {
        this(null, returnCode);
    }

    public Foo(String confirmationNumber, ReturnCode returnCode) {
        if ((returnCode == ReturnCode.OK && confirmationNumber == null)
                || (returnCode != ReturnCode.OK && confirmationNumber != null)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad combination of parameters.");
        }
        this.confirmationNumber = confirmationNumber;
        this.returnCode = returnCode;
    }

    public enum ReturnCode {

        OK, ERROR1, ERROR2, ERROR3, ERROR4, ERROR5;

    }

}
```

The problem with this approach is enforcing correct instantiation of the object. The calling code needs to know the rules of object creation (e.g., can't instantiate Foo with ReturnCode.OK and null confirmation number. )

Method 2:

Return an interface, or abstract type and create variations of Foo depending on success or failure to process the data in the method, like in the example below:

```
public abstract class Foo {

    public abstract String getConfirmationCode();

    public abstract ReturnCode getReturnCode();

}


public class GoodFoo extends Foo {

    private final String confirmationCode;

    private final ReturnCode returnCode = ReturnCode.OK;

    public GoodFoo(String confirmationCode) {
        this.confirmationCode = confirmationCode;
    }

    @Override
    public ReturnCode getReturnCode() {
        return returnCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String getConfirmationCode() {
        return confirmationCode;
    }

}


public class BadFoo extends Foo {

    private final ReturnCode returnCode;

    public BadFoo(ReturnCode returnCode) {
        if (returnCode == ReturnCode.OK){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("BadFoo cannot have a good return code");
        }

        this.returnCode = returnCode;

    }

    @Override
    public ReturnCode getReturnCode() {
        return returnCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String getConfirmationCode() {
        return null;
    }
```

Method 3:

Make return type a String and return confirmation number as String and for any bad return codes throw checked exceptions. This is a tried and tested approach and it will definitely work but what if there were additional parameters to return to the caller regardless if the response is a success or a failure? Or if there are multiple return codes for a success (e.g, ReturnCode.OK_WRITTEN_TO_DB, ReturnCode.OK_QUEUED etc.)

I'd like to know if there's a best practice to follow in this case?

Comment: Is the "bad" case considered an error? In Java, it's idiomatic not to have to check for success codes (as in C) to make the standard case clear and to use exceptions for error handling.

Comment: @chrylis Yes, bad case means data could not be processed for whatever reason. The consumer of the EJB service is a C application and the communication goes through a web service. Do you think that's why they're asking for a success code even though a non null confirmation number should be a proof of success?

Comment: I'd go with a checked exception. Keep the expected success path as clean and readable as possible.

Comment: @bez That's likely. In that case the wrapper code should take care of translating between idioms.

Comment: @chrylis You mean If I go with option 3 it is web services responsibility to translate the response into something meaningful for the client C application?

Comment: Right. The Web layer will, for example, translate an exception into an HTTP status code (perhaps 422), and the client code (even in Java) would normally be expected to check the code and then proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Method 3 is the Java way. Return the value and throw failure codes as exceptions.

Method 1 is closer to the Haskell way, and Haskell has ways to overcome the limitations you mentioned (e.g phantom types), but for Java, just stick to exceptions, the way the ancestors intended.

Comment: I updated Method 3 in my question. How would this work if there were more parameters to return weather success or a failure?

Comment: @bez In such cases, what I would do is combine methods 1 and 3. Use the class from method 1, but if the return code is an error, instead of returning it, wrap it in an exception and throw it. This way, the return value is always a success, but you can still handle failures `try { Foo goodFoo = getFoo(); } catch(BadFooException e) { Foo badFoo = e.getFoo(); }`

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend a **method 4**. Return the confirmation number in case of success, but throw a custom Exception if there is any error. Make the client responsible for handling the exception and retrieving the code from the custom exception object in case of failure.

Here's an example:

```
public class InvalidDataException extends Exception {

    public Integer errorCode;
    public InvalidDataException (Integer errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
}

public class ServiceClass {
    public String submitData(Data data) {
        //Do processing
        if(error1) {
            throw new InvalidDataException(100);
        }
        else if(error1) {
            throw new InvalidDataException(200);
        }
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString(); //conf number
    }
}

public class ClientClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String confNum = "";       
        Data data = new Data();
        //Build data
        ServiceClass sc = new ServiceClass();
        try {
           confNum = sc.submitData(data);
        }
        catch(InvalidDataException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred with the code " + e.errorCode);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

If there are multiple elements associated with the success case as well, I would recommend you develop a custom `Result` object. The service will build this object and set the necessary attributes such as success | failure flag, error code and others. The return value of the method will be this `Result` object. Client will have to fetch the necessary information from the `Result` object.

Comment: But what if there are multiple parameters to return in both cases and if there are multiple return codes associated with success? See updated method 3 in question.

Comment: @bez, If there are multiple elements associated with the success case as well, I would recommend you develop a custom `Result` object. The service will build this object and set the necessary attributes such as success | failure flag, error code and others.

Comment: Something like Method 1 in the question?